# How do you access a collection from the meteor shell?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to execute this query in a meteor shell, I need to use the meteor shell because one of the query parameters is a moment object.

```
date = moment().subtract(5, 'hours').toDate()
return Messages.find {createdAt: {$gte: date}}
```

In `meteor shell`:

```
> Messages = new Mongo.Collection("messages")
Error: A method named '/messages/insert' is already defined

> Messages
ReferenceError: Messages is not defined
```

I have to run the code in the meteor shell because the query uses moment objects.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to do this by calling the following on the Meteor Shell:

```
MyCollection = Mongo.Collection.get("collectionName");
```

Replace "`collectionName`" with a string containing the name of the mongo db collection.

Also `Mongo.Collection.getAll()` to return all collections on the shell.

Comment: For this to work, you'll likely want to make sure you have this package: https://github.com/dburles/mongo-collection-instances